# Connecting to a Signalr Hub via native Java Android application

Tags: java, android, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am quite new to software development and currently working on a project where I connect to an existing Signalr hub via native Java Android application. The libraries for this sort of communication that I have found, have not been updated in a long time: https://github.com/SignalR/java-client.

Is it still viable to use the library above, even though it has not been updated? Or is there a better alternative?

I would have an easier time if I used Xamarin, but I would prefer using Java so that I do not have to learn things twice.

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you find any alternative ?

Comment: @mohnage7 unfortunately I have not, I resorted to working with Xamarin. It seems the java-client is really dead.

Comment: i use the java client there isn't good documentation on it but after a lot of looking around, i have a working implementation.